# How to style input popups (e.g. date and time) on Android?

Tags: android, html, css

`<input type="date">` and `<input type="time">` show a nice popup on Android.

**But is there a way to style these popups?**

Preferably without jquery/javascript alternatives.

[image: Android time input popup]
[image: Android date input popup]

Comment: Actually I really only need to change the color from green to red (to match my site's colors). Other additions such as seeing events inside the calendar would be nice, but are not a necessity.